# Web API Optional parameters in the middle

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following route mapping or WEB API

```
[Route("Foo/Id/{id=1}/bar")]
```

I want to make Id optional as above however from client side no matter what I call it route doesn't match and I get 404
I try things like

```
Foo/Id//bar
```

But doesn't work. Is there way to use optional parameters with web api if the parameter is not at the end?

Comment: Another way of doing it is have 2 routes, and have your resource like: `GetFooById(int id = 0)`. Both routes will point to that.

Comment: I know that way, but it's not feasible if the number of optional parameters grow. In that case there will be n! routes.

Comment: Can you give more information on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a method with 4 parameters optional and I want to write an attribute routing with it.

Comment: You could provide default value for the option parameter.

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "Foo/Id/{id}/bar",
        defaults: new { id = 0 }
    );

Comment: @Jakub It might be useful yes, although I was asking if it could be done via attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not use // in URL.
The only way to make things you want is to map 2 routes for one endpoint.
For examle

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "BarRoute",
   routeTemplate: "Foo/Id/{id}/bar",
   defaults: new { controller = "Foo" });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "BarDefaultRoute",
   routeTemplate: "Foo/Id/bar",
   defaults: new { controller = "Foo" });
```

Answer (score 0):

use 0 instead of blank parameter and when getting 0 use it like its blank.

Comment: What if 0 is a real parameter? It doesn't make this optional

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and my solution was to make the route attribute nullable and pass a null argument when I did not want to provide a value.  For you, this would be something like:

```
[Route("Foo/Id/{id:int?}/bar")]
```

I then handled the null condition in the logic of the controller action.  I guess you could assign a default value in the controller action like so (c#):

```
///<summary>
/// Get my foo's bars
///</summary>
[Route("Foo/Id/{id:int?}/bar")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int? id)
{
    var fooId = id ?? 1; // fooId will be of type System.Int32.
    ...
```

So you could call either of these:

```
~/Foo/Id/null/bar
~/Foo/Id/5/bar
```

This solution works for me.

Comment: I am sure it works but its pretty ugly

Comment: @Squibly It is ugly and I'd rather just avoid the scenario.  I can't remember what I was working on at the time or what my constraints were, but the implementation isn't very RESTful. I'd try something like ~/api/foos and ~/api/foos/{id} as separate endpoints and not have 'Id' in the root at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just add multiple routes to your controllers

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("api/old-log")]
public class LogController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        return Json(new { Foo = "bar" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[please refer to this article regarding route attribute](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

You could use it like this and provide defaults.

Your attribute would be looking like this:

```
[Route("Foo/Id/{id:int=0}/bar")]
```

and then handle 0 as if there was no value (as mentioned above).

Comment: I already tried it thus I asked this question. It doesn't work that way. If you add above route, Foo/Id//bar simply returns 404